# NodeJS - nodemon not restarting my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

I installed NodeJS (4.4.5) and then proceed to install nodemon (1.9.2) as well,
I follow all the instrucctions of instalation (npm install -g nodemon)

I created a new folder, inside I have my **server.js** with some basic code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response){
    response.writeHead( 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'} );
    response.write("Hello world");
    response.end();
}).listen(3000, 'localhost');

console.log('http://localhost:3000');
```

So when I run in my console "nodemon server.js" I get this:

```
[nodemon] 1.9.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
http://localhost:3000
```

(Which means that is running fine)

But when I make some changes in my server.js, It doesn't restart the server

What could be the issue?

Comment: seems to work ok for me using same versions and code. you sure you saved the file? :)

Comment: yes, I'm constantly making changes and saving, the only way I was able to restar my server was typing 'rs', like it says there

Comment: maybe you're running in a vm? i've had issues in the past with that https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/146

Answer (score 87, accepted):

In some networked environments (such as a container running nodemon reading across a mounted drive), you will need to use the legacyWatch: true which enabled Chokidar's polling.

Via the CLI, use either --legacy-watch or -L for short:

> nodemon -L

Comment: This is what solved my issue when running the server in a vagrant box with source files shared with the host.

Comment: This also resolved my problem when running my node in a vagrant box. Thank you

Comment: This solved my problem when working with WSL2 (Ubuntu18.04).

Comment: i had the same problem with monitoring a directory tree on a chromebook linux container. thank you, your solution fixed it.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue on nodemon 1.9.2 : 0 files were watched by nodemon

(try verbose mode `nodemon server.js -V` to get more information)

After some research, this issue was due to my root directory name : 
My root directory was named "mysite.git" thus nodemon was watching 0 file. I had renamed my root directory without the dot and nodemon now works as expected.

Remove all special characters from your root directory and nodemon should work as expected.

Comment: Also remove all special characters from your project *path directory*.

Comment: I had `./src/index.js` and had to remove the `./` from the beginning to make it actually watch the file!

Comment: my path to the root directory is relative too, and -L solved the problem. the problem was the root directory is on a virtual/linux container drive (on a chromebook).

Comment: This lead me to figuring out that I needed to add extensions to watch!

Comment: This was it for me as well. I had initialized a Git repo inside of another Git repo.

Answer (score 8):

You can try running like this `nodemon -L yourapp.js`, something like that:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -L index.js "
 }
```

And run command:

```
npm run dev
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I just hit what seemed to be the same issue where I would make changes to my code and save them but nodemon wouldn't restart my server. The only way I could update  was via 'rs' in the console. I ended here looking for a solution but then decided to just re-install nodemon as there was no good explanation for why it wasn't working:

```
npm uninstall nodemon
npm install nodemon
```

After reinstalling the automatic restart on code change worked.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the package.json file like this :

````
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
  },```

This may help you.
````

Comment: What is your idea here, I cannot see any help.

Answer (score 1):

Nodemon uses `SIGUSR2` signal for restarting the server, cross-check if your server is overriding the functionality of this process signal.
In my case, I was using heapdump module, which was resetting this signal, hence I started the server using:-

```
env NODE_HEAPDUMP_OPTIONS=nosignal nodemon app.js
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make Sure to add to scripts -> start  `--legacy-watch ./app`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --legacy-watch ./app  ./bin/www "
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried uninstalling nodemon, didn't work. You can try and uninstall nodemon globally, if it works. It didn't work in my case, so what I did is I deleted all the node modules from my system. They will be located at C:/users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm. I even reinstalled node into my system and then installed nodemon, then it worked.

Comment: this sounds like a different issue, not just the nodemon lib

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30978112)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it adding the path `C:\Windows\System32` to the system environment, after that, I had to restart Visual studio code and it worked!...

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9fIZViTNEA

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tyler2P thanks for the advice. Sure. I'll keep this factor in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows use Powershell, not WSL. If you want to use WSL, you have to move your project directory to the WSL home directory OR use nodemon -L on the command line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

solve it by adding the path

> C:\Windows\System32

to the system environment

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9fIZViTNEA

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution on YouTube. So, the solution is:

1. Copy this path:

> C:\Windows\System32

2. Go into 'computer/This Pc' properties then into 'Advance System Settings/System Settings'.
3. Then click on 'Environment variable' Button.
4. Then double click on 'Path' in User Variables section.
5. Then click on 'New' and paste this path :

> C:\Windows\System32

Comment: Just, can you add a link to the Youtube video ?

Comment: I don't think it is relevant. The user hasn't said he has issues on windows.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, or I understand why